# How can we redirect from a node's /latest URL if there is no latest moderation state when the user clicks it?

Tags: redirection

Drupal 9: We want to link users to the node's "/latest" URL but if there is not currently a latest version then they get an access denied message. We'd like to, instead, redirect the user to the node without the /latest

Example:

Going to site.com/node/7944/latest when there is no latest would redirect the user to site.com/node/7944

Comment: Programmatically? The easiest way probably would be to catch the access denied exception and set a redirect response. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/312473/redirection-from-user-login-to-another-page-for-logged-in-users

Comment: I would suggest a RouteSubscriber, check and handle, redirect before it throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you 4uk4, your suggestion worked.